# How do I find which columns in my pandas dataframe contain a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I am running a drop duplicates on my dataframe and I cannot run it on columns that contain lists.
I am trying to make a function that finds the columns containing lists before I drop duplicates.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,[1,2,3],1],[2,[2,3],2],[3,[3],3]], columns = ['a','b','c'])

    a   b           c
0   1   [1, 2, 3]   1
1   2   [2, 3]      2
2   3   [3]         [3,4]
cols = find_list_columns(df1)

cols 
['b','c']
```

Comment: You want to get column names having `list` in it and then drop them right?

Comment: I actually want to exclude these columns from my drop duplicates

Comment: So, you want to keep them right?

Comment: _I am trying to make a function that finds the columns containing lists before I drop duplicates._ Alright, is there an issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a custom function using [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) with [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) then use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to create a boolean mask and use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) over [`df.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html)

```
def has_list(x):
    return any(isinstance(i, list) for i in x)

mask = df1.apply(has_list)
mask 
# a    False
# b     True
# c     True
# dtype: bool

cols = df1.columns[mask].tolist()
# ['b', 'c']

df1.drop(columns = cols)
#    a
# 0  1
# 1  2
# 2  3
```

Comment: Thank you again Ch3steR. this is great

Answer (score 3):

Use `applymap` and `any`

```
In [556]: df1.columns[df1.applymap(type).eq(list).any()]
Out[556]: Index(['b', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

As @Ch3steR recommended

```
df1.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x,list).any()
```

Comment: Thank you. Feel free to add it to the answer. +1

Comment: @Ch3steR: Thanks, bro. I added the the answer :)

Comment: It was just a little suggestion no need to credit me actually. You did all the work. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe has only either **numbers** or **list**, then you can do that in one line like so:

```
print([key for key in df1.columns if df1[key].dtype == "object"])
```

Comment: columns of string also has dtype `object`

Comment: yeah.. that's why I said in "If your dataframe has only either numbers or list"

Comment: I just give `string` as an example to show that checking on `object` dtypes is not a recommended way due to `Object` dtype can hold any data type. Columns of numbers may also be dtype `Object` if somehow the construction or import of dataframe force it `Object`. Try this: `s = pd.Series([1, 5.3, 6], dtype='O')`. You will see `s` dtype is object while all its values are numbers

Comment: But do you agree that it's the fastest and easiest way if all values inside dataframe are either a number or a list?

Comment: thank you very much, I did have strings in my dataframe so I had to go with the others. Next time I'll do a better job framing my question!